# Python change module name to its realname

Tags: python

`app.py`:

```
import sys

for name, module in sys.modules.iteritems():
    print name
```

I get:

```
encodings
site
__builtin__
sysconfig
__main__
....
```

as you can see, the module name is changed to `__main__`.

I know this behaviour(`if __name__ == '__main__'`), but how can I change the module name back to its real name?

Comment: Why is this important? If it's really important just create a new entry point (module) that does nothing but import `app` and call its entry point function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `module` for your module:

```
print module
```

Output:

```
<module '__main__' from 'app.py'>
```